# Writing a new text file in python

Tags: python, file, python-3.x, split

I'm writing code that goes over a text file counting how many words are in every line and having trouble putting the result (many lines that each consist ofa number) into a new text file.

My code:

```
in_file = open("our_input.txt")
out_file = open("output.txt", "w")


for line in in_file:
    line = (str(line)).split()
    x = (len(line))
    x = str(x)
    out_file.write(x)

in_file.close()  
out_file.close()
```

But the file I'm getting has all the number together in one line.

How do I seperate them in the file I'm making?

Comment: `out_file.write(x + '\n')`

Answer (score 5):

You need to add a new line after each line :

```
out_file.write(x + '\n')
```

Also as a more pythonic way for dealing with files you can use [`with`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement) statement to open the files which will close the files at the end of the block.

And instead of multiple assignment and converting the length to string you can use [`str.format()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) method to do all of this jobs in one line:

```
with open("our_input.txt") as in_file,open("output.txt", "w") as out_file:
    for line in in_file:
        out_file.write('{}\n'.format(len(line.split())))
```

Answer (score 3):

Add newline in the file while writing

```
 in_file = open("our_input.txt")
 out_file =open("output.txt", "w")


for line in in_file:
    line= (str(line)).split()
    x=(len(line))
    x=str(x)
    out_file.write(x)
    #Write newline
    out_file.write('\n')

in_file.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

As the previous answers have pointed out, your need to write a newline to separate the ouput.

Here is yet another way to write the code

```
with open("our_input.txt") as in_file, open("output.txt", "w") as out_file:
    res = map(lambda line: len(line.split()), in_file)
    for r in res:
        out_file.write('%d\n' % r)
```